# javascript Replace sitename.com with sitename2.com when pasted into textarea

Tags: javascript, replace

Just wanted to know how i would replace sitename.com with sitename2.com whenever a user pastes it into a textarea, even on multiple lines.

Example, a user pastes
sitename.com/index.php?v=somecrap
sitename.com/index.php?v=somecrap2
sitename.com/index.php?v=somecrap3

upon pasting it is replaced with
sitename2.com/index.php?v=somecrap
sitename2.com/index.php?v=somecrap2
sitename2.com/index.php?v=somecrap3

Let me know if its possible or not with javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `paste` event?

But it does fire before pasting is completed, to editing pasted contents, I need `setTimeout` to wait it completed.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WnAhF/)

```
var pasted = document.getElementById("pasted"),
    replace = function() {
      pasted.value = pasted.value.replace(/sitename\.com/g, "sitename2.com");
    };
pasted.addEventListener("paste", function () {
  // Wait to the pasting completed
  setTimeout(replace, 0);
}, false);
```

Comment: ...but is not cross-browser safe. You should mix both solutions.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html Oh, I forgot to care Opera and older IEs..

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible with a clever combination of an "onchange" handler and a regular expression. A jquery snippet with an example:

```
function replacer() {
    var txt = $(this).val ();
    txt = txt.replace ( /sitename\.com/g, 'sitename2\.com' );
    $(this).val ( txt );    
} 

$('textarea').mouseup ( replacer ).keyup (replacer);​
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/u97WD/4/

Comment: wow that was fast :) however it does not replace them all when you paste multiple lines?